# Win32 API : how to make Edit Text to accept unsigned float only in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I'm trying to learn win32 api :)

I have some edit text placed in DialogBox and I want it to accept only float numbers that are greater than 0

I was able to make that edit text to accept Integers only by using the style "ES_NUMBER" in resource file but I can't find any way how to make it accept positive float values
please I need your help thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to handling the `EN_CHANGE` notification you also have the option of [subclassing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the window. This will allow you to restrict which keystrokes are valid and only allow numbers, a dot, etc. The example below shows how to create an edit control, subclass it and filter the input so that only specific characters are allowed. It does not handle operations such as pasting from the clipboard so you will want to expand it to meet your specific requirements.

The benefits of this approach are that you do not need to add any additional code to the parent window to filter the edit control. This allows you to use it throughout your application without having to duplicate a lot of code. Another benefit is it eliminates possible flicker that occurs from updating the contents of the control to remove unwanted characters.

```
static WNDPROC OriginalEditCtrlProc = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(uMsg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        // Make sure we only allow specific characters
        if(!    ((wParam >= '0' && wParam <= '9')
                || wParam == '.'
                || wParam == VK_RETURN
                || wParam == VK_DELETE
                || wParam == VK_BACK))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return CallWindowProc(OriginalEditCtrlProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateCustomEdit(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hParent, UINT id)
{
    HWND hwnd;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        _T("EDIT"),
        _T(""),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
        0, 0, 200, 40,
        hParent,
        reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(id),
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    if(hwnd != NULL)
    {
        // Subclass the window so we can filter keystrokes
        WNDPROC oldProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(SetWindowLongPtr(
            hwnd,
            GWLP_WNDPROC,
            reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(MyWindowProc)));
        if(OriginalEditCtrlProc == NULL)
        {
            OriginalEditCtrlProc = oldProc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Captain that really opened my eyes to subclassing (it's new thing for me ^_^ ) that was exactly what I was looking for except only one small problem which is I can type multiple "." chars in the Edit

Also there's similar great example I found about subclassing for any one interested : http://www.go4expert.com/articles/hook-windows-control-messages-t19754/

thank you again Captain and every one helped :)

Comment: You're quit welcome. When processing a period in the WM_CHAR handler get contents of the edit control and see if a period is already present. If it is just bail out.

Comment: I seem to be getting a reinterpret_cast error, which is weird becasue LRESULT is LONG_PTR        `'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__cdecl MyApp::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'LONG_PTR'`

Comment: Never mind, it seems that `MyWindowProc` is not supposed to be a part of a class

Answer (score 3):

Use EN_UPDATE notifications and if the user types a minus sign, simply delete it.  The net effect will be exactly what you want: a control that accepts only positive floats.  Don't use EN_CHANGE because that is sent after the control has been redrawn, and changing the input then will require another redraw, which will give the impression of the control flickering.

Comment: thank you for the help but I think in this case subclassing the edit text as Captain mentioned is much better because it allow you to restrict what the user can type rather than checking and deleting each unwanted char :)

Comment: +1 for the answer. My pardon for disturbing, but I have a similar task to perform. I was wondering if you could edit this answer with a small pseudo code just to illustrate your point, or maybe you can provide some links to code examples. I use **pure** `Win32 API`. I would highly appreciate your help and would strive not to bore you-I just need a small example of using `EN_UPDATE` properly. Hopefully we shall stay in touch. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff There is sample code [here](http://www.ucosoft.com/simple-cedit-validation.html) using MFC. Removing the MFC shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to handle it myself ( I believe I can handle it on my own ) in order not to disturb you. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

There is no unsigned float in c++ so not possible!

You will probably have to validate explicitly.

Comment: If the OP wants to restrict the edit control to [rootbeer] floats they _will_ have to validate explicitly. Either by subclassing the edit control or by reading the value from the control when necessary.

Comment: @ Bathsheba thx for answering but I'm not sure what do you mean are you referring to use EN_CHANGE notification and check for the input and than correct it ?

Comment: wow it's really annoying that I can't even make unsigned float variable !

Comment: @user Why would you need unsigned float?